# Does my code follows the principle of Polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, super

I'm a newbie to Java and I attempt to achieve Polymorphism with the requirements of using the following:

- super keyword
- overriding
- having more than two classes
- getting the user's input
- using do-while
- creating objects

It doesn't have any errors but I doubt if it still makes any sense.
Does it follow Polymorphism still? If not, How can I improve it?

Here is my code:

```
public class Sample Code {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare variables
        String name, fSong;
        int aNum;
        
        fSong = " ";
        
        Zayn a1 = new Zayn();
        a1.makeMusic();
    
        Songs a2 = new Songs();
        a2.setName("Zayn");
        a2.displayName();
        a2.makeMusic();
        
        Lyrics a3 = new Lyrics();
        a2.displayName();
        a3.makeMusic();

        //get values
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter Your Name (2-20 characters): ");
            name = in.nextLine();
        }while(name.length() < 2 || name.length() > 20);

        System.out.print("\nCHOOSE YOUR FAVORITE SONG :\n\n");

        System.out.print("[1] Pillowtalk \n");
        System.out.print("[2] Dusk Till Dawn\n");
        
        do{
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Choice (1-2): ");
            aNum = in.nextInt();
        }while(aNum < 1 || aNum > 2);
        
        //determine aNum
        if(aNum == 1) {
            fSong = "Pillowtalk";
        }else if(aNum == 2){
            fSong = "Dusk Till Dawn";
        }
        //Display output
        System.out.print("\n[OUTPUT]\n\n");
        
        System.out.printf("Your Name: %s\n", name);
        System.out.printf("Your Favorite song of Zayn is: %s.\n", fSong);
        
    }
}

class Zayn{
    String name;
    
    Zayn(){
        this.name = this.name;
        
    }
    
    void makeMusic(){
        System.out.println("Zayn makes music");
        
    }
}

//superclass
class Songs extends Zayn{
    Songs(){
        super();
    }
    
    void makeMusic(){
        System.out.println("Pillowtalk Lyrics: Pillowtalk, my enemy, my ally\n");
        
    }
    
    
    public void setName (String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }
        
    
    void displayName(){
        System.out.println("\nName of Artist: " + this.name);
    }
}
class Lyrics extends Zayn{
    @Override
    void makeMusic(){
        System.out.println("Dusk Till Down Lyrics: I'll be with you from dusk till dawn\n");
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think that will compile: `public class Sample Code {` as an example.

> Does it follow Polymorphism

It sorta demonstrates it, but it doesn't look like a clear application of the principle.

What's a Zayn, and why is a Song a Zayn and a Lyric is a Zayn?

Polymorphism is to represent a hierarchical typing of your objects.  E.g. you could have `Animal` as base class, with `Mammal` and `Reptile` extending.  This can be further extrapolated to have `Dog` and `Cat` extend from `Mammal`, while `Lizard` and `Snake` extend from `Reptile`.

Bear in mind that if class `Foo` extends class `Bar` then any instance of `Foo` is also a `Bar`. This is sometimes called a "is-a" relationship, because in this scenario, a `Foo` is a `Bar`.

Comment: Will it fix it if I rename the parent class as ZaynSongs instead? Then Pillowtalk and DusktillDawn as its subclasses since they're Zayn's songs?

Comment: Those are more specific instances, than types.  What are some different properties of different types of songs?  Also, I'm guessing Zayn is an artist?  I feel old...

Comment: To follow the song metaphor, you could have a `normal song` and then different genres of a song, doo wop, heavy metal, backmasking (playing the song backwards), etc...  Then each of these subclasses can subtly change the lyrics of the song when outputted.  The doo wop could add some doo-wops at the end of every sentence.  Heavy metal could add random buzzing noises.  Backmasking could reverse all the lyrics...  All while keeping a parent classes same method signature.

Comment: Those sound more like different instances of songs, as opposed to different types.  Put another way, that sounds more like different property values rather than different properties or behaviours.